# How to hook fopen() on Windows inside a class

Tags: c++, windows, hook, fopen

I need to hook fopen() on Windows as member of a class. I tested this code:

```
void **IATfind(const char *function, HMODULE module);

// Define the function pointer type for the original function
typedef FILE*(__cdecl* popen)(const char* filename, const char* mode);

struct Hook {
  // Declare the original function pointer
  popen orig_fopen;
  // Define the detoured function
  FILE* __cdecl hook_fopen(const char* filename, const char* mode) {
    printf("Rewrite fopen: %s\n", filename); // need to know here which module make fopen() call
    return orig_fopen("hook_test.txt", mode);
  }
  void DetourIATptr(const char *function, void *newfunction, HMODULE module) {
    void **funcptr = IATfind(function, module);
    if (funcptr == 0) {
      printf("cannot find function address\n");
      return;
    }

    DWORD oldrights, newrights = PAGE_READWRITE;
    //Update the protection to READWRITE
    VirtualProtect(funcptr, sizeof(LPVOID), newrights, &oldrights);

    orig_fopen = (popen)*funcptr;
    *funcptr = (void*)&Hook::hook_fopen;

    //Restore the old memory protection flags.
    VirtualProtect(funcptr, sizeof(LPVOID), oldrights, &newrights);
  }
  void Do() {
    //DetourIATptr("fopen", (void*)hook_fopen, 0);
  }
};
int main(int argc, CHAR *argv[]) {
  Hook hk;
  hk.Do();
  printf("main\n");
  fopen("myfile.txt", "w");

  return 0;
}
void **IATfind(const char *function, HMODULE module) { //Find the IAT (Import Address Table) entry specific to the given function.
  if (module == 0)
    module = GetModuleHandle(0);
  PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pImgDosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)module;
  PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pImgNTHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)pImgDosHeaders + pImgDosHeaders->e_lfanew);
  PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pImgImportDesc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((LPBYTE)pImgDosHeaders + pImgNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);

  if (pImgDosHeaders->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) {
    printf("libPE Error : e_magic is no valid DOS signature\n");
    return 0;
  }
  for (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR *iid = pImgImportDesc; iid->Name != NULL; iid++) {
    for (int funcIdx = 0; *(funcIdx + (LPVOID*)(iid->FirstThunk + (SIZE_T)module)) != NULL; funcIdx++) {
      char *modFuncName = (char*)(*(funcIdx + (SIZE_T*)(iid->OriginalFirstThunk + (SIZE_T)module)) + (SIZE_T)module + 2);
      const uintptr_t nModFuncName = (uintptr_t)modFuncName;
      bool isString = !(nModFuncName & (sizeof(nModFuncName) == 4 ? 0x80000000 : 0x8000000000000000));
      if (isString) {
        if (!_stricmp(function, modFuncName)) {
          printf("address finded\n");
          return funcIdx + (LPVOID*)(iid->FirstThunk + (SIZE_T)module);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get this: error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'FILE *(__cdecl Hook::* )(const char *,const char *)' to 'void *'

If I define hook_fopen() out of **Hook** struct, the code works fine but I need to use class to can hook fopen() in multiple dll modules.

Alternate solution: can avoid to use class but need to know which module make fopen() call, so must to identify hmodule in hook_fopen() I need this for an application which load more dll modules and check if this modules act as malware.

Comment: The hook function must have the same signature as the hooked function. Non-static functions inside classes have different signatures than functions outside of classes. This is a fundamental fact of C++. Therefore it seems your only option is to make `hook_fopen` static. Of course this means that you can no longer access `orig_fopen` from `hook_fopen` unless you also make that static.

Comment: Since making `hook_fopen` static might not be acceptable to you, can you explain why using a class helps you use this code in multiple modules. That part isn't clear (to me at least).

Comment: How I say, need to hook fopen() in multiple dll modules. When a module call fopen() will call hook_fopen() in fact, but there I need to know which module make fopen() call. I need this for an application which load more modules and check if this modules act as malware.

Comment: So you are trying to add context to the fopen call. That is not possible in any straightforward way.

Comment: `hook_fopen` must not be member or class/struct. `popen orig_fopen;` is wrong. must be `extern "C" { extern PVOID __imp_fopen;}` `IATfind` not need at all (i already not say about how it implemented)

Comment: You says "is wrong" but on my compiler and my testing works :) Show me your solution, is very easy to say "is wrong"...

Comment: I tried in hook_fopen()  "if (GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
                        (LPCTSTR)&fopen, &callerModule))" also VirtualQuery() but return my app instead the caller module.

Comment: wrong by design. are you understand what is `__imp_fopen` ? and that class member function have additional parameter ?

Comment: RbMm if you want to help tell me how to do it, don't ask me what I know, I don't need teachers full of them, otherwise please leave it to those who really want to help!!! If you read what I wrote and understood, you should think that I need all the functions that works with files, not just fopen.

Comment: I'm fairly certain your `hook_fopen` and `orig_func` member need to be static.  Otherwise, what's keeping track of "this" when the function is invoked?

Comment: A hook function cannot be a non-static member function. Otherwise how can the system know what object to invoke it on?

Comment: hooking is by module I suppose